Ошибка при попытке запустить программу с использованием turtle
Выдается ошибка при попытке запустить программу на Turtle Python
import math
import turtle

turtle.bgcolor("black")
turtle.pencolor("black")
turtle.shape("triangle")
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.fillcolor("orangered")

phi = 137.508 * (math.pi/180.0)
for i in range(180+40):
    r = 4 * math.sqrt(i)
    theta = i * phi
    x = r * math.cos(theta)
    y = r * math.sin(theta)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.setheading(i*137.508)
    turtle.pendown()
    if i < 160:
        turtle.stamp()

    else:
        turtle.fillcolor("yellow")
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.left(-5)
        turtle.circle(500,25)
        turtle.right(-155)
        turtle.circle(500,25)
        turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.done()

Выдается ошибка:
valerymokrytska@Valerys-MBP pythooon %  /usr/bin/env /usr/bin/python3 /Users/valerymokrytska/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-darwin-arm64/bund
led/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 64249 -- /Users/valerymokrytska/Downloads/pythooon/Flower.py 
E+00000.028: Error while enumerating installed packages.
             
             Traceback (most recent call last):
               File "/Users/valerymokrytska/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/common/log.py", line 361, in get_environment_description
                 report("    {0}=={1}\n", pkg.name, pkg.version)
             AttributeError: 'PathDistribution' object has no attribute 'name'
             
             Stack where logged:
               File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
                 return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
               File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
                 exec(code, run_globals)
               File "/Users/valerymokrytska/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/__main__.py", line 91, in <module>
                 main()
               File "/Users/valerymokrytska/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/__main__.py", line 21, in main
                 log.describe_environment("debugpy.launcher startup environment:")
               File "/Users/valerymokrytska/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/common/log.py", line 369, in describe_environment
                 info("{0}", get_environment_description(header))
               File "/Users/valerymokrytska/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/common/log.py", line 363, in get_environment_description
                 swallow_exception("Error while enumerating installed packages.")
               File "/Users/valerymokrytska/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.0.0-darwin-arm64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/common/log.py", line 215, in swallow_exception
                 _exception(format_string, *args, **kwargs)
             

DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.


Код рабочий. Или проблема в самом python и его настройках или с менеджером пакетов

попробуйте в IDLE запустит. Там питон напишет ошибку(в какой строке).
